# How to add conditional data into itext table cells

Tags: java, pdf, itext, cell

I'm trying to input data from that I've parsed from a JSON file into a table. I'm using Java on Eclipse with itext external jar (since I'm trying to output a PDF).
The data to be input is conditional.

```
                  table.addCell("Annual Leave*"); 
                  if(ltype=="annual"){
                  table.addCell(from1);
                  table.addCell(to1);
                  table.addCell(n);
                  }
                  else{
                     table.addCell("");
                      table.addCell("");
                      table.addCell("");
                  }

                  table.addCell("Sick Leave(certified)**");
                  if(ltype=="sick_leave_cert"){
                      table.addCell(from1);
                      table.addCell(to1);
                      table.addCell(n);
                  }
```

This is what I've tried to do. However, my end PDF document has an empty table.

Comment: You don't tell us how many columns you defined for the `table`, and it looks like you're using an old iText version (the current version is iText 7.1.3).

Comment: The table has 4 columns and 5 rows. Yes, I'm using 7.0.7
Either way, I'm wondering if the syntax is all right. Because when I have no if/else conditions, the data is put into the cells. 
The same doesn't happen otherwise.

Comment: You have a table with 4 columns to which you add only 3 cells if the conditions aren't met. In that case, the table doesn't have any row that is complete. Hence the table isn't drawn. You need at least one complete row. (In other words: change the number of columns to 3, or add an extra cell.)

Comment: I have 4 columns.1 of the cells has fixed data. So I didn't show it in the code snippet. Hence, 3 cells left

Comment: You should provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) if you want a useful answer. By omitting a line in your code, you received a useless answer. Now I feel silly for giving you a useless answer (whereas I am not to blame because you didn't give me all the information that was needed). This way, you have blown your chance that I will revisit your question.

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity.
The first cells of each column are fixed. Like in the snippet "Annual Leave, Sick Leave etc.
The 2nd, 3rd and 4th are empty. They're filled in with data only if a condition is met. The condition is specified in the if statement. However, on running the program, my table only shows the 1st cells filled while the others remain empty even though the condition is true.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not really itext related, it is about Java String handling: You compare Strings like this:

```
if(ltype=="annual")
...
if(ltype=="sick_leave_cert")
```

In Java the `String` type is not a primitive type. Thus, String comparison using `==` checks whether both sides resolve top the identical String object, not whether the Strings on both sides represent the same characters in sequence.

To check whether two Strings represent the same character sequences use the `equals` method instead:

```
if("annual".equals(ltype))
...
if("sick_leave_cert".equals(ltype))
```